# vscode extension: call git.branch with a new branch name and avoid the inputBox

Tags: git, vscode-extensions

I am trying to write a little helper extension to ease the creation of feature branches. I already have a view of recently active work items and a button to create a feature branch from a specific item.
The name is already being formatted correctly, but I do not want to be responsible for the branch creation logic when the functionality is already built into vscode.

My first attempt was to simply call `executeCommand` and pass in the command and requested branch name like this:

```
vscode.commands.executeCommand("git.branch", branchName);
```

Sadly the `branchName` parameter is simply being ignored and a text input appears just as it would when executing the command via the command palette. The easy solution would be to simply <s>steal</s> borrow the branch creation logic or make a cli call, but I am stubborn and would like to avoid doing that if possible.

I can barely find any information regarding this topic anywhere.

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands does not cover git commands

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/command#command-uris covers passing parameters to commands via uris, but this too does not work for me

I would appreciate any leads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can avoid the InputBox opening by using the API that the git extension exposes, see [git extension api](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/git/src/api/git.d.ts).

> The Git extension exposes an API, reachable by any other extension.
>
> Copy `src/api/git.d.ts` to your extension's sources;
>
> Include `git.d.ts` in your extension's compilation.
>
> Get a hold of the API with the following snippet:

```js
const gitExtension = vscode.extensions.getExtension('vscode.git').exports;
const git = gitExtension.getAPI(1);
```

The above is from the extension description for the `@builtin` git extension description.

So you could use:

```
const branchName = 'test';

try {
  const extension = vscode.extensions.getExtension('vscode.git');

  if (extension !== undefined) {
    const gitExtension = extension.isActive ? extension.exports : await extension.activate();
    const gitAPI = gitExtension.getAPI(1);

    const activeEditorUri = vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.uri;
    const wsFolderUri = vscode.workspace.getWorkspaceFolder(activeEditorUri).uri;

    const theRepository = gitAPI.getRepository(wsFolderUri);
    await theRepository.createBranch('test', true);
  }
} catch (error) {}  // log error
```

Comment: The git API did work for me. I got the API like [GitLens used to](https://github.com/gitkraken/vscode-gitlens/blob/30e1d290e8f337d56596a030ff097eeabdd98eb7/src/git/gitService.ts#L3042-L3053) (they do it differently now).
I got the current workspace folder and just called `getRepository` using that, which lets me call `createBranch` without any problems.

Comment: I edited the answer based on your input.  I still don't know why the other `getRepository(<some github repo link here>)` wasn't working.  Is the new version what you are using?

Comment: Almost! You get typing if you include the typedef file of the git API and use `getExtension<GitExtension>`. I also don't use `activeTextEditor` and instead just get the first folder of the workspace. I might update my code to use `activeTextEditor` and fall back on the workspace folder if I get an `undefined`. The rest is pretty much the same, except I also log an error if `extension` is undefined. (and I made sure to copy the `git.d.tf` to `src/@types/`, so I wouldn't have to change the default tsconfig)

Comment: How do you test this? My extension does not load when I try to depend on `vscode.git`: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/159421

Comment: I test it in a command that I trigger, I wait to make sure the git extension has loaded.  That seems appropriate to the question about creating branches.  Are you/cam  you waiting for the git extension to initalize?

Comment: @Ark-kun See above comment.  Also you can test if an extension is active: `Extension.isActive`

Comment: Hmm. When I debug my extension, the only active extension (`vscode.extesnions.all`) is my own extension despite VSCode showing a big list of active extensions (including the built-in Git extension). How do you usually wait for an extension? `setTimeout`?

Comment: Actually, VSCode does not even let my extension to start at all if I put `extensionDependencies` in `project.json`. So it's not possible to wait.

Comment: @Mark I did another test. When I do not include `extensionDependencies` in `project.json`, I cannot call `extension.isActive` since `extension` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `git.branch` command does not support parameters, as you can see here

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/10e6e876822fa2da15fb68e8a6f1fb9aa8d94ce2/extensions/git/src/commands.ts#L1884-L1887

In this case, I suggest you should to open an issue in VS Code repo and ask to the VS Code team to expand the command, to support such scenario.

They recently added a *random branch name* feature, so I suppose such request would be well received.

Hope this helps

Comment: I falsely assumed I could just use the exposed commands from the git extension. @Mark pointed out, that the built-in git extension exposes an API.

Comment: Good to know that importing the Git API works. I totally forgot to suggest you that. It is a bit more work to do, but you still use the built in Git support. Good luck with your extension.